# Content Manager Explorer does not open context menus

Tags: cme

I am using SDL Tridion 2013 SP1. In Content Explorer context menus were not opening (I am trying to install Content Porter but Tools menu is not opening). I am using IE 10 and I have configured IE as explained in [here](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011&lang=en-US&docid=task_4BDA54F0C0E94625A0BD06C0113DE482&query=ActiveX#addHistory=true&filename=NoContextMenusDropdowns.xml&docid=task_4BDA54F0C0E94625A0BD06C0113DE482&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&eventType=lcContent.loadDoctask_4BDA54F0C0E94625A0BD06C0113DE482), but still it is not working. Can any one help me to fix this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer's *Compatibility Mode* has caused issues for me. Even when not set intentionally, I believe IE's default sets `Display intranet sites in Compatibility View`, which likely applies for most SDL Tridion setups.

In IE 10 this breaks a few things in the Content Manager Explorer including the Tools tab and Ribbon Toolbar buttons in form view. Try unchecking the option in IE under **Tools** > **Compatibility View Settings** then refresh the browser.